# Check Available Storage Space

Tags: software-recommendation, disk, disk-usage

I am not able to find a way to determine how much disk space is free. The methods I am seeing are not clear and provide information that appear to need to be put together for a big picture. Is there a third party utility program that can provide a clean estimate of remaining disk space?

Comment: Use the `df` command. Read `man df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install stacer which is available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

It is an all in One System Optimizer and App Monitoring Tool for Linux.

Besides showing what disk space you have available it also performs many other functions:

```
Act as a control panel for the startup apps
Helps to clean or remove the unnecessary cache or system log files or even the trash files.
You can now easily stop or start any particular system services or processes.
Helps to sort out the processes as per CPU, PID or even memory usages.
Uninstallation or removing an application from the system is much easier now.
Shows various system resources of the last 60 seconds of RAM, CPU, Disk, Network activity and CPU load average, etc.
You can active, delete or inactive the package repositories for Linux.
```

This is an example screen (from my system) showing that I'm using 13.4Gb of 116.4Gb on my SSD:

[image]

Stacer also offers a stable PPA for installing this in Ubuntu and its derivatives. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oguzhaninan/stacer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install stacer
```

You can also remove it completely by the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove stacer
```

and then remove the PPA repository from `Software & Updates >> Other Software` Tab.

In addition, the third tab `File Systems` in the native tool *System Monitor* also shows the desired information.

[image]